# Back button not working on Tizen RD-PQ Reference device

Tags: tizen

I've compiled the Tizen2.2 source code. I've generated an image out of the build and flashed the image on to the RD-PQ reference device. After flashing of the image I've observed that in most of the applications the back button is not working properly. I've noticed this in inbuilt MyFiles application and also in most of the settings menu(e.g, in display settings), in which the back button is not working at all.

Could any one assist me in solving this issue?

Comment: Is it software back button or hardware back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button problem is a bug in the Tizen source code.

I've posted this question in the Tizen developer forums (https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/back-button-not-working-on-tizen-rd-pq-reference-device) , where I got the answer at the following link.

https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/latest-image-rd-pq
https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/back-buttons

If anyone faces the similar issue with the back button they can follow this forum topic for the work around to this problem.